# How to display date on item in ListView?

Tags: java, android

Hi guys i want to diplay date for every item in listview. I tried something but it shows a number not in date format. I think that i need to convert that number but i don't know how. This is my code. Thanks to evryone in advance

```
public void getAudio() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri audioUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor audioCursor = contentResolver.query(audioUri, null, null, null, null);

        if(audioCursor != null && audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int audioTitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int audioDate = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED);

            do {
                String currentTitle = audioCursor.getString(audioTitle);
                String currentDate = audioCursor.getString(audioDate);
                arrayList.add(currentTitle + "\n" + currentDate);
            }
            while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I think that i need to convert that number but i don't know how.` unless your date returns as a string from an api, chances are you'll always have to convert/manipulate it

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things to consider here.
First, you have to convert that number/string into date object in java. Secondly, once you have date object, you can convert it to any date format you would love. For example Dec 23, 2020 etc.

If you have date in milliseconds you can use like this

1- `Date currentDate = new Date(currentDateTime); //creating Date from millisecond`

2- Now we have date object, it can be formatted now.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yy:HH:mm:ss");
           //formatted value of current Date
           System.out.println("Milliseconds to Date: " + df.format(currentDate));
```

Let me know, if it is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've solved in this way: if(currentDate != null) { currentDate = formatter.format(audioDate); }

Comment: That's great. I will suggest you please recheck if you have got the correct results. I mean input date and out date are same.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing something like this:

at first define how you want your date to look like, eg.:

```
DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

then format your date to fit desired format:

```
if(audioDate  != null){
            audioDateFormatted = dateFormat.format(audioDate );
        }
```

Comment: It works, but with some changes because audioDate is an Integer not a String. So I solved in this way: if(currentDate != null) {
                    currentDate = formatter.format(audioDate);
                } after creating the Strings

Comment: I'd only add that it could be wise to use `SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance()`, which will fetch the date format for the current locale